# How do I fix my bathtub knobs that rotate the wrong way after cartridge replacement?

Tags: plumbing

I replaced both hot and cold delta cartridges on my bathtub and now I have no leaks but they turn on and off backwards. What to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I replaced o-rings in my tub faucets & diverters a few weeks ago. I put them all in backwards so they turned the wrong way. I opened everything back up, flipped them over (two alignment tabs, 180° opposite each other) and now they work as expected.

I'm more than willing to bet that your cartridges can, and have been, installed backwards and that flipping each one to the 180° opposite rotation will fix the problem.